# Two way communication Python and C++

Tags: c++, python

Would it be possible to have a C++ dll call Python scripts and at the same time, have a python script call functions in the C++ dll that created the python instance in the first place?

What library could I use? And if none, are there any best practices? Would it be the best to use shared memory for the communication or should I use some sort of service which is able to conduct things?

My target platform is Windows

Comment: Check out [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html).

Comment: This is called [embedding Python](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html)

Comment: You might consider Cython, which makes the interface singificantly simpler than using the straight Python/C API and can also be used along with embedding. I'd post an answer but I have experience with this only on Linux ;).

Comment: I see how embedding python can be used to call python functions from C++, but I want to call C++ functions from the python I embedded too. I this anyhow possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use an external library written in C/C++ in Python using the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module. Beware though that C++ [mangles](https://blogs.oracle.com/petesh/entry/c_name_mangling_and_function) function names, and ctypes can only use functions that are declared `extern "C"`! (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python))

To call a Python script from C++ you have two options:

- Start a new Python process with the script name as an argument. On windows you can e.g. use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this.
- [Embed](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) Python in the C++ app as Janne Karila mentioned.

Note that these things don't have much to do with *communication* between programs.

A library doesn't really communicate because it's not a process. It just supplies functions and data for a process to *use*.

And you can start a process from another process without communication whatsoever between them.

To communicate between processes you use interprocess communication. The different methods of doing that on Windows are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).